# Show address in WebView of Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to show the address bar in the the WebView of Codename One (BrowserComponent or WebBrowser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebView component doesn't include an address bar.  Just the web view.  You can create your own address bar though.  Just add a text field to your UI.  And update its value in the onLoad listener of the webview.